Which step does SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext class represent actually?
While trying to write a DiagnosticAnalyzer class for a project I am working on, I have experienced confusion on how each method are intended to work or to be used.
My understanding from reading MSDN Doc is that the compilation of a .NET source code is made of 4 steps: 1. Parsing source code into syntax tree, 2. Importing metadata and retrieving symbols, 3. Binding, 4. Production of IL Code.
The callback method that are passed to each Register{Step}Action method are registered to be invoked at each Step the method refers to in the name.
For example, the callback passed to the RegisterSyntaxNodeAction will be invoked at certain point of Step 1 of compilation which I mentioned above: (1. Parsing source code into syntax tree).
And this is the source of my confusion; upon reading what property and method SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext type offers, I found out that it has Compilation and SemanticModel properties, which is weird to me because the information that these property give out seems impossible to be retrieved during the production of syntax tree. It has not gotten into the point of semantic analysis and completion of compilation, right?
I suppose the reason behind my frustration is my unclear vision on how compilation and code analysis actually work.. Maybe compilation and code analysis are completely separate to each other, in a way that code analysis happens after compilation, as opposed to my current belief?
And if that is the case, I wonder why certain Context class of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics has SemanticModel property (e.g. SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext), while some other do not (e.g. SymbolAnlysisContext). If code analysis happens after the completion of compilation, then shouldn't every Context class have some common properties publicized?
